# Why did Allie's Mom disapprove of Noah?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-notebook

In *The Notebook*, why did Allie's mom disapprove of Noah? At the beginning, she said he was "trash" and she also hid the 365 letters that he sent to Allie. Of course one explanation is that Allie's mom thought that Noah was too poor for Allie. However, I think another reasonable explanation is that the mom regretted choosing her current husband over her first love, who was shown at the end of the movie, and didn't want to see her daughter have the happier life she couldn't. What do you think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the contrary, maybe she wanted her daughter to have a happy life with no regrets!

> Why did Allie's Mom disapprove of Noah?

Disapproving of Noah, hiding all his letters to Allie etc, all the things she did because of Noah's social and financial status, because he belonged to a lower class than where they belonged. She didn't want her daughter's husband to be financially struggling throughout their life.

> However, I think another reasonable explanation is that the mom
>   regretted choosing her current husband over her first love, who was
>   shown at the end of the movie, and didn't want to see her daughter
>   have the happier life she couldn't.

Now if she wanted that she wouldn't have shown the man to Allie. She would  have kept everything inside her and would force her daughter to marry Lon, to  whom she is engaged.

She revealed her past to Allie to show what regret is. How it (love) haunts her to this present day. She shows her love to Allie also to show her that if she would have married that person she would probably had to live a hard life financially.

Deep down her heart she wants her daughter to be happy. So, she wants her daughter to know both sides of the coin. She wants her daughter to know the consequences of her decisions, be it Lon or Noah.

Comment: I was thinking maybe the mom changed her mind about choosing Allie's fate, since she started to feel bad about it. But what you say makes more sense. I listen to too many conspiracy theories.